# why the for loop getting skipped?

Tags: java

I want to add products to the array in a specific order(from smallest to largest) but for some reason the code skip the for loop that do the shifting part. I tried to make the condition " products.length-2 " but it still doesn't work.

```
if(products!=null){
  for(int i=0; i<products.length; i++){
    if(products[i]!=null && product.getItemNum() < products[i].getItemNum()){
      index=i;
      temp = products[index];
      for(int j=products.length-1; j<=0; j--){
        products[j+1]= products[j];
      }
      products[index]= product;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: CHeck your If condition properly.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider that your `products` array contains 2 elements.
The first iteration of the inner `for` loop:

```
for(int j=products.length-1; j<=0; j--){
```

will evaluate to:

```
for(int j = (2) - 1; j<=0; j--){
```

So as you can see, your terminating condition is the origin of the problem.
And since you're counting backwards, it should be `j >= 0`, not `j <= 0`:

```
for(int j=products.length-1; j >= 0; j--){ // j >= 0
    products[j+1]= products[j];
}
```